# Parameters are not passing to next state in stateprovider angularjs ui router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am stuck at this issue passing the parameter in state go function but its not going to the next state. Default state parameter values shown in next state Following is my code for passing parameter

```
var params = angular.copy($stateParams);
params[menuItem.params] = menuItem.value;
$state.go('abc.index', params);
```

Please help in the issue

Comment: Could you show us state definitions and whatever menuItem is?

Comment: @ŁukaszStaniszewski state params are like this {orgId: "abc", abType: "ab", Id: "4811989909", request_type: "xyz"}  i want it to be like this in the next state {orgId: "abc", abType: "ab", Id: "4811989909", request_type: "xyz", new_param: 30}. I hope you could help how can i achieve this